# Actionscript Flex Mobile Requested extension com.adobe.ane.productStore could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a FLEX Mobile project.  I have tried several FLEX and AIR SDK.  I am currently using FLEX 4.6.0 and AIRSDK 15.0 that I downloaded from Adobe.  I have added "Product Store.ane" to my build path.  The ane file was downloaded from Adobe as part of Adobe Gaming SDK 1.4.  I can import com.adobe.and.prodictStore in my actionscript code.  My application description file contains the following:

```
    <extensionID>com.adobe.ane.productStore</extensionID>
```

Why do I get the Requested extension com.adobe.ane.productStore could not be found error when I try to run my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good folks at Milkman Games solved this for me.  In Project Properties, Flex Build Packaging, Apple iOS (in my case), click the Native Extensions tab and make sure the Package checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose FLEX 4.6.0 and AIRSDK 15.0 are incompatible, you should use Apache Flex if you want to use AIR 15.0. And if ANE compiled with latest AIR version you have no other way to use it.

Comment: I originally used ApacheFlex 4.13.0 with AIRSDK 15 and had the same problem.